# java 8 parallel stream confusion/issue

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am new to parallel stream and trying to make 1 sample program that will calculate value * 100(1 to 100) and store it in map.
While executing code I am getting different count on each iteration.
I may be wrong at somewhere so please guide me anyone knows the proper way to do so.

**code**:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main{    
    static int l = 0;       
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        letsGoParallel();
    }       
    public static int makeSomeMagic(int data) {
        l++;
        return data * 100;
    }        
    public static void letsGoParallel() {
        List<Integer> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 1; i <= 100 ; i++) {
            dataList.add(i);
        }
        Map<Integer, Integer> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
        dataList.parallelStream().map(f -> {
            Integer xx = 0;
            {
                xx = makeSomeMagic(f);
            }
            resultMap.put(f, xx);
            return 0;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println("Input Size: " + dataList.size());
        System.out.println("Size: " + resultMap.size());
        System.out.println("Function Called: " + l);
    }
}
```

[Runnable Code](https://www.jdoodle.com/a/Jml)

**Last Output**

> Input Size: 100
>
> Size: 100
>
> Function Called: 98

*On each time run output differs.
I want to use parallel stream in my own application but due to this confusion/issue I can't.
In my application I have 100-200 unique numbers on which some same operation needs to be performed. In short there's function which process something.*

Comment: You have an shared static field `l` and you do not synchronize access/modifications to it

Comment: @ernest_k, yes but Input and Map result should be same every time. It also differs sometime.

Comment: Both l and resultMap are accessed in a thread unsafe way so you should expect to lose some operations.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: so what should be ideal way to do so !

Comment: You could use `AtomicInteger` for `l` and `ConcurrentHashMap` for `resultMap`. But a better way would be to avoid side-effects altogether, as proposed in answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your access to both the `HashMap` and to the `l` variable are both **not** thread safe, which is why the output is different in each run.

The correct way to do what you are trying to do is collecting the `Stream` elements into a `Map`:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> resultMap =
    dataList.parallelStream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap (Function.identity (), Main::makeSomeMagic));
```

EDIT: The `l` variable is still updated in a **not** thread safe way with this code, so you'll have to add your own thread safety if the final value of the variable is important to you.

Comment: like @ernest_k said in comment on the question for l you could use an AtomicInteger to make it thread safe

Comment: @Eran, thanks for the answer. Let me try the code with your snippet.

Answer (score 2):

By putting some values in `resultMap` you're using a [side-effect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects):

```
 dataList.parallelStream().map(f -> {
            Integer xx = 0;
            {
                xx = makeSomeMagic(f);
            }
            resultMap.put(f, xx);
            return 0;
        })
```

The [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/index.html?java/util/stream/package-summary.html) states:

> Stateless operations, such as filter and map, retain no state from
>   previously seen element when processing a new element -- each element
>   can be processed independently of operations on other elements.

Going on [with](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness):

> Stream pipeline results may be nondeterministic or incorrect if the
>   behavioral parameters to the stream operations are stateful. A
>   stateful lambda (or other object implementing the appropriate
>   functional interface) is one whose result depends on any state which
>   might change during the execution of the stream pipeline.

It follows an example similar to yours showing:

> ... if the mapping operation is performed in parallel, the results for
>   the same input could vary from run to run, due to thread scheduling
>   differences, whereas, with a stateless lambda expression the results
>   would always be the same.

That explains your observation: *On each time run output differs.*

The right approach is [shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52828928/2838289) by @Eran

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully it works fine. by making `Synchronied` function `makeSomeMagic` and using Threadsafe data structure `ConcurrentHashMap`
and write simple statement

```
dataList.parallelStream().forEach(f -> resultMap.put(f, makeSomeMagic(f)));
```

Whole code is here :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main{  
static int l = 0;
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    letsGoParallel();
  }
  public synchronized static int makeSomeMagic( int data) { // make it synchonized
    l++;
    return data * 100;
  }
  public static void letsGoParallel() {
    List<Integer> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 1; i <= 100 ; i++) {
      dataList.add(i);
    }
    Map<Integer, Integer> resultMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();// use ConcurrentHashMap
    dataList.parallelStream().forEach(f -> resultMap.put(f, makeSomeMagic(f)));
    System.out.println("Input Size: " + dataList.size());
    System.out.println("Size: " + resultMap.size());
    System.out.println("Function Called: " + l);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- There is no need to count how many times the method invoked.
- `Stream` will help you do loop in byte code.
- Pass your logic(function) to `Stream`, do not use no thread-safe variable in multi-thread(include `parallelStream`)

like this.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ParallelStreamClient {
//  static int l = 0;---> no need to count times.

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        letsGoParallel();
    }

    public static int makeSomeMagic(int data) {
//  l++;-----> this is no thread-safe way
    return data * 100;
}

public static void letsGoParallel() {
    List<Integer> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        dataList.add(i);
    }
    Map<Integer, Integer> resultMap =         
    dataList.parallelStream().collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> i,ParallelStreamClient::makeSomeMagic));
    System.out.println("Input Size: " + dataList.size());
    System.out.println("Size: " + resultMap.size());
    //System.out.println("Function Called: " + l);       
}
```